# Is there a way to work with nested data structures like you work with XMLtree in R?

Tags: r, xml, nested, data.table

Are there any data structures, i.e. nested lists, data.tables, tibbles, which have a package, or any other way, to access their fields just like it is an XML document?
What should be supported?

- accessing all nodes on all levels which contain a specific attribute
- filtering nodes by name, no matter which level they are at or which parental structure separates them

Comment: I think this question needs a little work: asking us to *"recommend a package"* is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); if I understand, nested-lists would be most similar to XML's arbitrary nesting, but to best inform the topic it would help to know the scope or scale of your intent, but without more specific use-case details (with/without sample data), it's difficult to say. I suggest the question is too broad and needs details; SO is more about concrete programming questions, not discussions. Can you please focus the question to be more concrete?

Comment: @r2evans it is a very simple binary, alternative-choice question: whether there is or whether there is no such package; no recommendation are required because I've already conducted my own research

Comment: I'm trying to help, ivan866, but your "simple binary question" is asking us to recommend a package. This is expressly off-topic. To make it more about a concrete programming question (versus researching a topic), I suggest you can add some example to your question to make it more interesting, more focused, and less about trying to do your research via a question on StackOverflow. I'm not trying to be pedantic or critical, I'm trying to help you improve your question.

Comment: @r2evans man, the problem with such requirements is the high entry threshold; a person who asks for help cannot spend time on providing multiple examples, formatting datasets and at the same time, making the question 'interesting'

Comment: Instead of "person who asks", it sounds like "person who asks for help and is in a time crunch". The premise that the asker "cannot spend time on providing multiple examples" is expressly putting the onus on the answerer. I suggest an alternative to that view is that StackOverflow is not intended or architected well for first-research-efforts, instead it should be used after initial research has demonstrated possibilities, code has been attempted on some form of input/data, and it does not work as expected. This is my understanding, perhaps I'm misinterpreting you or the SO community.